# No project templates are compiling with Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

On clean a Windows 10 64 machine, I have installed Visual Studio 2017 RC (along with ALL components) and no projects are building at all. They are all failing with this error:

> Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic
>   information may be found in files in the temporary files directory
>   named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.

When i investigate the log file it mentions it says:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 7300:
===================== 07/01/2017 19:30:19 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)    at
Microsoft.Build.Shared.BuildEnvironmentHelper.get_Instance()    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.ReadApplicationConfiguration()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.get_ConfigurationSection()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.<get_ToolsVersions>d__8.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadEachToolset(Dictionary`2
toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1
initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolsets(Dictionary`2
toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1
initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String&
msBuildOverrideTasksPath, String& defaultOverrideToolsVersion)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadAllToolsets(Dictionary`2
toolsets, ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader,
ToolsetConfigurationReader configurationReader, PropertyDictionary`1
environmentProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties,
ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.InitializeToolsetCollection(ToolsetRegistryReader
registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configReader)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2
globalProperties, IEnumerable`1 loggers, IEnumerable`1 remoteLoggers,
ToolsetDefinitionLocations toolsetDefinitionLocations, Int32
maxNodeCount, Boolean onlyLogCriticalEvents)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.get_GlobalProjectCollection()
at
Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.HandleNodeConfiguration(NodeConfiguration
configuration)    at
Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.HandlePacket(INodePacket
packet)    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.Run(Boolean
enableReuse, Exception& shutdownException)    at
Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.StartLocalNode(CommandLineSwitches
commandLineSwitches)    at
Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.ProcessCommandLineSwitches(CommandLineSwitches
switchesFromAutoResponseFile, CommandLineSwitches
switchesNotFromAutoResponseFile, String& projectFile, String[]&
targets, String& toolsVersion, Dictionary`2& globalProperties,
ILogger[]& loggers, LoggerVerbosity& verbosity, List`1&
distributedLoggerRecords, Boolean& needToValidateProject, String&
schemaFile, Int32& cpuCount, Boolean& enableNodeReuse, TextWriter&
preprocessWriter, Boolean& debugger, Boolean& detailedSummary, Boolean
recursing)    at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String
commandLine)    at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main()
=================== 07/01/2017 19:30:19 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)    at
Microsoft.Build.Shared.BuildEnvironmentHelper.get_Instance()    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.ReadApplicationConfiguration()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.get_ConfigurationSection()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationReader.<get_ToolsVersions>d__8.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadEachToolset(Dictionary`2
toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1
initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolsets(Dictionary`2
toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1
initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String&
msBuildOverrideTasksPath, String& defaultOverrideToolsVersion)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadAllToolsets(Dictionary`2
toolsets, ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader,
ToolsetConfigurationReader configurationReader, PropertyDictionary`1
environmentProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties,
ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.InitializeToolsetCollection(ToolsetRegistryReader
registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configReader)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2
globalProperties, IEnumerable`1 loggers, IEnumerable`1 remoteLoggers,
ToolsetDefinitionLocations toolsetDefinitionLocations, Int32
maxNodeCount, Boolean onlyLogCriticalEvents)    at
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.get_GlobalProjectCollection()
at
Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.HandleNodeConfiguration(NodeConfiguration
configuration)    at
Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.HandlePacket(INodePacket
packet)    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.Run(Boolean
enableReuse, Exception& shutdownException)    at
Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.StartLocalNode(CommandLineSwitches
commandLineSwitches)    at
Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.ProcessCommandLineSwitches(CommandLineSwitches
switchesFromAutoResponseFile, CommandLineSwitches
switchesNotFromAutoResponseFile, String& projectFile, String[]&
targets, String& toolsVersion, Dictionary`2& globalProperties,
ILogger[]& loggers, LoggerVerbosity& verbosity, List`1&
distributedLoggerRecords, Boolean& needToValidateProject, String&
schemaFile, Int32& cpuCount, Boolean& enableNodeReuse, TextWriter&
preprocessWriter, Boolean& debugger, Boolean& detailedSummary, Boolean
recursing)    at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String
commandLine)    at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main()
===================
```

I have repaired the installation and done a full uninstall/install that doesnt make a difference.

Tried turning logging on under Tools -> Options to diagnostic but it doesnt show me which file it is refering to in the error message in the log file.

This works with existing projects and new projects. Any ideas?

NOTE: I did originally install VS on a non default non system drive but removed this and re did it to the default installation.

Comment: I suggest filing a ticket at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com

Comment: Does the soluton build from the commandline?

Comment: i have fed it back within VS already including re2ference to this question. On the command line it does build when using msbuild.exe ConsoleApp1.csproj" without errors or warnings. thats what makes it even worse

Comment: Thanks for filing this over on the VSFeedback site, Kyle. I've routed it to the MSBuild team to take the first look, based on the stack -- any information that we find will get posted over on the entry over there (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10606/no-projects-compiling-at-all.html). --Matt--*